# C# 2.0 Display ALL Windows start up items (programs,dlls,services) for all users and be able to enable or disable them

Tags: c#

Id like to have a tab on my windows form application where there would be a drop down list for each user that shows DLLS, Services, Programs that start up with that user. Where can i look to start this project? iv searched google the closest thing i can find is this:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/121859-getting-all-startup-items/

except for all users, and have it display services and DLL's that load as well.

Answer (score 0):

As the link you've added shows, to list all startup programs, use [Win32_StartupCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394464%28VS.85%29.aspx).  To list all services you can use [Win32_Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418%28VS.85%29.aspx) in a similar fashion. You should be able to use one of the samples on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394602%28VS.85%29.aspx) page as a starting point.

Just make sure that the user account you run under have the correct rights (look at the links above for more info).

Answer (score 0):

You could download [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and then check the same places in your program. Or put in a link to the autoruns.exe at live.sysinternals.com, which is what I would do.

Comment: Autoruns would be PERFECT the everything column is amazingly nice and the ability to load offline accounts is excelent, but the idea is that id like it to be integrated within my application not just link to it, also id like for it to not require a internet connection.

Comment: You could check the same places in your program. Autoruns makes it obvious where it looks for things.

Comment: im still learning how can i say get all the items from "CurrentUser\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
and
LocalMachine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"

put it in a checklist box? and then have control over it? (like say have all of the enabled ones checked, and all the disabled ones not checked, and if i check one it enables it, and if i uncheck one it disables it?

Comment: Autoruns "disables" entries by moving them to another location; I believe with the registry, it's a subkey named `Disabled` or something similar. If in doubt, run Technet's Process Monitor, and it will tell you what Autoruns is doing.